# Как получить json-строку пришедшую с сервера?

Tags: php, html, json, api

Отправляю запрос на сервер

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://0.0.0.0:1234/qwerty" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="cmd"> 
            <input type="text" name="fio">
            <p><input type="text" name="usl"></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
        </form>

        <?php

        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

После нажатия на кнопку "Отправить" приходит ответ в виде json-строки на новой странице.
Используя php нужно:

1. Отправить запрос так, чтобы когда придет ответ (json-строка) остаться на странице с формой.
2. Записать json-строку в переменную и распарсить; или сразу распарсить, если это возможно, чтобы потом вывести часть данных в предназначенное для этого поле формы.

Comment: `jQuery ajax`. Переменная придет в ответ.

Comment: @Наталия Что бы остаться в той странице есть 2 варианта, или вы должны action формы оставить текущую страницу, и в нем обработать пост запрос, или сделать пост запрос с помощью ajax запроса.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan если в action я уберу адрес сервера, то где тогда его прописать, чтобы запрос обработался? Ajax я не знаю.

Comment: @Наталия В том же файле тогда должны обрабатываться запросы, пхп кусок кода обработки запроса должны быть в этом самом файле.

Comment: @Наталия И еще один момент, давайте уточните в вопросе где вы хотите парсить json строку?
Вы написали вот так `И как записать эту json-строку в переменную, чтобы потом распарсить?`.
Обясните каким языком хотите парсить строку?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan при помощи средств php. Понадобилось добавить на сайт, а сайт на php написан, сказали, что код должен быть на php.

Comment: @Наталия Давайте по порядку и пунктами что вам нужно сделать добавьте в вопрос, от а  до я, Потом скажу как сделать.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan добавила

Comment: @Наталия Получилось?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan ещё не успела попробовать, отпишусь о результатах.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan спасибо, работает! только результат (json-строку) не могу записать в переменную. $rez=curl_exec($curl); в браузер выводит json-строку, а в переменную записывает цифру "1".

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59496/discussion-between-razmik-galstyan-and-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример вашего кода где я постарался обяснить как можно это реализовать без ajax:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['command'])){
//                Здесь ваша логика сервера которую нужно будет писать в тот же файл
//                $tmp_field который вы хотите вставить в форму
            }
        ?>
        <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="cmd"> 
            <input type="text" name="fio">
            <p><input type="text" name="usl" value="<?php echo isset($tmp_field) ? $tmp_field : ''; ?>"></p> <!--Пример где вставляеться переменная-->
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Обратите внимание на несколько вещей:

Если в форме не прописывать action то означает что action тот же самый URL.
Строка `if(isset($_POST['command']))`  означает что мы пришли на наш url методом post(сделали клик submit в форме).
И там уже делаем обработку наших данных и в переменных сохраним те значения которые нам нужны.
А это `value="<?php echo isset($tmp_field) ? $tmp_field : ''; ?>"` пример вставки тех переменных которые вы хотели вставлять в форму, там проверяеться существование элемента, потому что если мы на странице не по клику на submit то эти переменные не будут обявлены и мы должны проверять их существование прежде чем использовать в нашем коде.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для этих целей [AJAX](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-intro)

Для быстрой реализации можно использовать библиотеку [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://0.0.0.0:1234/qwerty',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    command: $('input[name="command"]').val(),
                    fio: $('input[name="fio"]').val(),
                    usl: $('input[name="usl"]').val(),
                },
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log("success");
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            })
            .always(function() {
                console.log("complete");
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://0.0.0.0:1234/qwerty" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="cmd"> 
        <input type="text" name="fio">
        <p><input type="text" name="usl"></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>
</body>
```

в переменной data функции done будет ваш уже распарсенный ответ с сервера